# Using a callback function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback

I've been breaking my head over this for several hours now, I'm pretty new to javascript overall so please bear with me.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

- show a 3 seconds div before a video plays (using the Vimeo api)

**What I've tried:**

- I've tried using .setTimeOut, problem is it only fires once, so the video plays for less than a second and then stops.
- .setTimeInterval also doesn't work in my case since it fires at an interval and not continuously.
- .delay() is only for jquery effects (correct me if I'm wrong)

**What I'm trying now; using a callback parameter**

- I'm trying to add a callback so it fires my second function (in which the video starts) after it did the first function, with the delay(3000)

**My code**

```js
// SHOW DIV 3 SECONDS BEFORE VIDEO STARTS
(function($) {

  $(document).on("click", "a.short-button", function videoStart(callback) {

    $('.short_preloader').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    callback();

  });

  // DO THIS FUNCTION AFTER THE DELAY
  videoStart(function() {

    var vidframe = $('.embed-container.short-embed iframe'),
      status = $('.status');

    vidframe(function() {

      var player = $f(this);
      player.api('play');

    });

  });

})(jQuery);
```

My function shows the .short_preloader div for 3 seconds, and should fire the second part of the code afterwards.

Thank you so much in advance!

Victor

Comment: You could look into [`Promise`](https://italonascimento.github.io/applying-a-timeout-to-your-promises/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) works asynchronously. You need to wait for it to complete and then call the `callback` function:

Instead of

```
$('.short_preloader').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
callback();
```

do this:

```
$('.short_preloader').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut(callback);
```

See the following example, which works like you want:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.ad').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut(play);
});

function play() {
  $('.video').show();
  console.log('playing video');
}
```

```css
.ad, .video {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Start video</button>

<div class="ad">An ad</div>
<div class="video">Video player</div>
```

Comment: @Victor -- You're trying to call a function without defining it. It is a syntax error; observe the console logs to verify it. See the demo snippet I've attached in my answer, and try to change your code similar to it.

Comment: Thank you for bearing with me, I've fixed the syntax error, it fires the second function but only for less then a second. Do you know how I can fix this perhaps?

Comment: @Victor -- I'm not sure what does that mean, but I can see that a green box appears for ~3s before the video plays.

Comment: The delay works and your fix also fires the callback, but the video plays for less than a second and then stops again.

Comment: The problem is google chrome! It works in Safari and Firefox but for some reason Chrome stops playing the video in less than a second..